# Python application only emits one time - real-time chat application

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am building a real-time chat application utilizing Flask SocketIO, Python, & JavaScript.
I have two main problems I have not been able to solve.

1) **When the user types and sends a message (the first time), it shows up twice.** After refreshing the page, the page properly displays it only one time. *In the console log, the `"inside announce message"` marker to show where the program is shows up 2x. The `"end of send message section"` from the python file only occurs once.*

2) **Subsequent messages the user tries to send do not get displayed in the chat window**, although after refreshing the page, they are properly displayed in order. *The `message_data` is properly logged on the console (in a previous `socket.on` function) as well as properly logged in the terminal from the `print(message_data)` python side. It does not seem to move from the end of `def sendmsg(message_data)` back into JS to the `socket.on("announce message")`.*

After observing the console log and what python prints to my terminal window, it seems that there is a failure for the message data to be sent from the python application to the JS file.

The `application.py` file:

```py
@socketio.on("send message")
def sendmsg(message_data):

    room = session.get("current_channel")
    # add the new message to the list
    channelmessages[room].append(message_data)
    # if the messages exceed 100, delete the first one
    if (len(channelmessages[room]) > 100):
        channelmessages[room].popleft()
    emit("announce message", message_data, broadcast=True)
    print("end of send message section")
    print(message_data)
```

*note: if I remove `broadcast=True`, the first message sends only once, but then other users do not see anything. I have not been able to implement a namespace, and for this project, only really need one chat room.*

The `scripts.js` file:

```js
socket.on('announce message', message_data => {
      console.log("inside announce message")
      //event.preventDefault();
      var message_list = document.getElementById('comment-list');
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = `<div>
                        <li><b>${message_data["user"]}:</b> ${message_data["message_content"]}</li>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        <li><small class="text-muted">${message_data["timestamp"]}</small></li>
                      </div>`;
      message_list.append(li);
      li.scrollIntoView();
    });
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! I've been struggling with this project for an embarrassingly long time. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you are establishing two connections from the client? That would explain why a broadcast ends up showing the same message twice, and a non-broadcast shows it once, but no other clients get the message.

Comment: Oof... I wouldn't know if I was or not. Any particular functions or lines I should look for in my code to tell if that's what is happening?

Comment: Difficult to say, how messy is your code? It shouldn't be that hard to find the connection calls in your JavaScript.